# Use Side Panel Navigation mode in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm looking for a way to use Side Panel for navigation between pages in the Acumatica Framework. 
Similar to what described this help [page](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(6))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=4ddf2c8d-5b67-425c-8862-34e10256dacf)  but using code. I couldn't find any document or windows mode in PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode which is doing that. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do side navigation from a GI, information from that link in your question should suffice. If you want to do it for a screen through code, then it can be done by specifying the WindowMode to be Layer.

```
throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "")
{
    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Layer
};
```

You can also specify an action in a customization project without using any code and define the action type to be that of a side panel. which will achieve the same result as in a GI but for a normal screen. This is much more flexible and cleaner than the other solution

[image]